# Discriminant Analysis of Principal Components for Candidate SNPs

Tags: r, pca, rda, linear-discriminant

I just ran a redundancy analysis on my SNP dataset, and I have candidate SNPs from it. I would like to run a DAPC on this data, but the [tutorial](http://adegenet.r-forge.r-project.org/files/tutorial-dapc.pdf) has left me a little confused. This is because I believe I already have my data in the clusters and I would just like to run the DAPC, but it's just not working for some reason due to these errors, and I believe I'm doing something wrong before I even get to this point, but I don't know what

Comment: Going through the code I definitely did something wrong there (and I totally get the documentation being really long). The problem I am running into now is the "SNP" column is a factor, and I need it in numeric form. But when I type "cand1$snp <- as.numeric(cand1$snp) it just changes the data in that column to "1,2,3,4,5...". I did get the data to plot when I converted the snp column from factor to numeric, it's just that it got converted to something that isn't my data. Do you think you can help me out here?

Comment: I just added the line of code that got me to the error, I'm starting to think I don't even need the SNP column, but I'm not sure

Comment: find.cluster works on " ‘a data.frame’, ‘matrix’, or ‘genind’ object. For the ‘data.frame’ and ‘matrix’ arguments, only quantitative variables should be provided.

Comment: Yes, you don't need the SNP column, but you have only one column with a variable. It's doesn't make sense to do PCA on one vector right. You need to get back your original data and let find.cluster do the PCA and clustering

Comment: So maybe I should combine all three datasets into one large column and do it then? Basically making 3 separate groupings within the dataset?

Comment: Hey.. i don't understand what you mean by making 3 groupings. what you basically need, is more than 1 variable to do clustering.